# Calling a static method on a TextChanged event from a class that is not in the code-behind file

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm working on a WPF application and am trying to bind a method to the TextChanged event that is not in the code-behind file. When the method is in the code behind file, I know that this can be accomplished simply by using:

```
TextChanged="MyMethod"
```

What I am looking to do is use a static method from another class (NOT in the code-behind file). Something that in theory would look like:

```
TextChanged="MyClass.MyOtherMethod"
```

I have tried to figure out how to reference the class and the method, but haven't been able to figure it out. It doesn't seem like I should need to create a resource library - is there a way to reference my class directly?

Comment: You can always create a new method in the class itself that does nothing but call the method in the other type.  Not sure if that's required in WPF though; don't use it much personally.

Comment: [WPF 4.5 Supports MarkupExtensions in Event Handler declarations in XAML](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/wpf-45-%E2%80%93-part-6-markup), though the problem is Microsoft was too lazy to implement any of these, so you'll have to implement it yourself. The good part is that, as everything in WPF, it's reusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily add a static event handler in code behind:

```
textBox.TextChanged += MyClass.MyOtherMethod;
```

given that the event handler looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void MyOtherMethod(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create event handler and call your static method from it. Something like this:

```
myText.TextChanged += myText_TextChanged;

void myText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
     MyStaticHelper.Execute();
}
```